# XCode Archive for app store Submission

Tags: xcode, project, archive, workspace

i have several apps in the AppStore but now i am struggling with one of the apps submission.

I added to my app the chart module, and i used AMCharts for that, so to make it work, i added the AMChartLibrary project into my project, and everything works fine either usgin the simulator and the device itself for testing, and now I am ready to submit the new version to appstore and then the nightmare starts

When i run the archive to create the file to be submitted, it falls under Other Items instead iOS Apps, this disables the button "Upload to App Store", my best guess is that the AMChart library can be used for MAC and iOS apps, and for some reason the xCode organizer is not identifying it as iOS app...

I know i am missing something, but i am not finding it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i should change the skip install for the subproject under Build Settings.